# How to use Lucene to query a CSV field

Tags: csv, lucene, umbraco

We're using Umbraco which has a built in search system built on Lucene.

Each document on the website contains a list of tags, these are indexed and held by Luence as a single field containing the tags in CSV format.

For example:

```
Red,Green,Blue
```

However when we search against this field through Umbraco (also using [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/)) we don't get the correct behaviour.

**Searching for 'Red' works, however a search for 'Green' or 'Blue' doesn't.**

From my understanding of Lucene this is all down to **the analyser not understanding the CSV format**. The analyser needs to tokenise using the comma to break into tokens.

However I'm at a loss at how to achieve this.

It seems like it must a common problem, so I must be missing something very obvious.

Comment: Are you using Examine for the search index?

Comment: Yes - however as I say, I've done the search through Examine and also Luke

Answer (score 0):

I have recently just built an Umbraco 6.1.3 site that does exactly this. Tags are added to a "Tags" property of a document type which are indexed in a comma separated format.

The Umbraco site has all the default index settings, so nothing is modified.

When I open up the "External" content index in Luke I can see that the "tags" field is Indexed, Stored and Tokenized (amongst other things), and has the values stored as expected:

[image]

If I search in Luke using `tags:lorem` or `tags:ipsum`, both return the correct results.

If your tags field is not being tokenized, then I would check the analyzer you are using. The `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer` is preferable as it will take this into account. I'm fairly sure the `WhitespaceAnalyzer` won't.

Alternatively, you could intercept the Umbraco document on the 'Indexing' event, create a new Lucene field called "tags_mod" and add the `tags.Replace(",", ", ")`. This way they should be indexed properly. You would of course have to search on "tags_mod" and not "tags". This feels a little hacky but perfectly valid. It's a great approach for combining textual content into a single indexable field, e.g. if several fields all the the same bias and there is no need to index, tokenize and store them all separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that CSV does not work with Lucene. As discussed on the [Umbraco forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/24714-Searching-csv-fields-using-examine), you need to bind a function to the `GatheringNodeData` Examine event, which allows you to do custom indexing.

You use this function to split the CSV field by spaces instead of commas, inserting this data as a new index field and including it in the `<IndexUserFields>` section of the examineIndex.config

```
public class ExamineEvents : IApplicationStartupHandler
{
    public ExamineEvents()
    {
        ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection[INDEX_NAME].GatheringNodeData
         += ExamineEventsGatheringNodeData;
    }

    void ExamineEventsGatheringNodeData(object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IndexType == IndexTypes.Content)
        {
            var node = new Node(e.NodeId);                
            IndexCsv(e, node);                
        }
    }

    private void IndexCsv(IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e, Node node)
    {
        if (node.NodeTypeAlias == "CsvPropertyDocType" &&
           !string.isNullOrEmpty(node.GetPropertyValue("CsvProperty")))
        {
            e.Fields.Add("CsvFieldSearchable", node.GetPropertyValue("CsvProperty").Replace(","," "));
        }
    }
}
```

where `CsvProperty` is the name of the CSV property,  `CsvPropertyDocType` is the name of the document type containg the property, and `INDEX_NAME` is your Examine index name.

Comment: Not sure about Lucene not being able to analyze CSV formats, my example demonstrates that that it can - or at least Examine's implementation can. It depends on the Analyzer used.